# How to link metrics from different services

Tags: redis, microservices, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

Assume we have two services `A` and `B`, and a metric `X` (say it counts the total number of user requests). The asynchronous request passes thru service `A`, where metric `X` is created (or its value is incremented). Service `A` then responds to the user with an 'OK' answer. After a few moments, the actual response can be returned (also asynchronously) from one of services `A` or `B` depending on its content. And when that's done, we need to create / increase the value of another metrics `Y` and `Z` which depend on metric `X`. Say `Y` counts the total number of successful user requests, and `Z` counts the total number of user requests that were completed in less than or equal to 3 seconds.

So, according to this we have five metrics:

```
X - serviceA_user_requests_total

Y1 - serviceA_user_requests_success
Y2 - serviceB_user_requests_success

Z1 - serviceA_user_requests_duration(le="3000")
Z2 - serviceB_user_requests_duration(le="3000")
```

The question is how to link those metrics if metric `X` will always appear in service `A`, but `Y` and `Z` will appear in both services. I guess I can somehow link `Y1`, `Y2` and `Z1`, `Z2` in Prometheus to get the real total number from their sum, but how can I link `Y2` / `Z2` with `X` in the code of service `B`? It's important to note, that we have the ability to associate the request with the response using the `request-id` parameter from our metadata. But what is the right way to do it?

The very first (and very bad) solution I thought of was to create a metric with a `request-id` label on each request. Then I supposed I could aggregate all of them using this label and get the desired result. But the documentation (and logic) says it's a bad practice due to [high cardinality](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels). So I abandoned the solution.

The only decent solution that came to my mind was to use shared storage (like Redis cache). In this case, in service `A`, I can temporarily put the request metadata into the storage, where the key is our `request-id` and the value is a current timestamp. Then, in service `B`, if the request was successful, I'll take the value directly from the storage by `request-id` and take the difference from the current time and the stored timestamp. But I'm wondering if it's a good solution or if there's a better one, especially if it can be done using something out of the box from Prometheus or related libraries.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "link metrics"? And especially "[link] in the code of service `B`"? When you are talking about `request-id`, do you want some kind of traces? If so - they are extremely different from metrics: metrics are for aggregated data (**total** number of requests). For traces (and for logs) there are separate tools - not Prometheus.

Comment: @markalex Sure. Imagine a bot - you ask it to turn the radio on, and it answers "Sure thing, just in a second!" and gives you radio content to play. The message you asked goes thru service `A`, the message it speaks also goes thru service `A`, but the radio content goes thru service `B`. We need to count all user requests, successful requests and successful requests that were done in <= 3 sec. Let's say a successful user request is a full cycle, starting from service `A` when you asked the bot about something, until it responds with both voice and radio content.

Comment: But the thing is that you need to somehow "link" the response in service `B` with the request (and bot's voice response) in service `A` to count them as one "successful user request". Thus, by "linking metrics" I meant creating a metric `X` and `Y`s with `Z`s and linking them by the `request-id` parameter. I don't know if I'm using the word "link" correctly though, English is not my native language. Also, maybe it's better to say "How to link a request in one service with a response in another, so that they're counted as one unit, and incerement the metric only once"

Comment: Oh, and forgot to say that, of course, before the bot gives you a voice answer and radio content - there's a lot of work and different API calls where an error may occur, so that's why we need a metric for a successful scenario processing.

Comment: Ah, then answer is quite simple: don't. Metrics should represent simple things. In this case total number of "responses" per type of response. So if service A provided something - increment counter for metric of A. If B - for B. And no business logic in metrics themselves.

Comment: If you need to track per-user counts, most likely Prometheus is a wrong tool for the job: cardinality will be through the roof. Consider logging tools, like Loki, instead.

Comment: And, if you decide to use Prometheus, consider using proper [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) instead of your `_duration` metric.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say not to use metrics for high level concepts. Business concepts is fair use of metrics, IMO. I do agree that the use case is not suited for the typical metrics instruments (gauge, counter, etc).

Comment: @insotriplesix Another alternative to using logs would be to record events for the different stages that the end-2-end user request goes through. Those events would be pushed through an event bus, and consumed by a reporting service. There you could process the different events and generate different types of metrics. It's more elaborate than using logs, but provides more flexibility.

Comment: @pca, probably I failed at conveying my idea clearly, sorry. What I meant: expose raw data, like "number of requests", not business logic data like "number of requests on business days that have T in the name of the day and was on full moon". Business rules are subject to [frequent] change, and any such change will render metrics useless.

Comment: Got it, guys. Thanks for the help & advice